# Batch script to tell if process is running or not

Tags: batch-file

I am very new to batch files and am trying to create a script that checks if a process is running and alert if the process is/is not running. This is what I have gotten from google, but isn't working the way I am wanting.

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq example.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "example.exe">NUL if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Program is running
```

Comment: This isn't bash, it's Windows Batch. They're entirely different scripting languages.

Comment: You appear to be missing a space and a 2 before your second `NUL` redirect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm running it in bash.  It sees it as valid syntax, but doesn't do what is required.

Comment: You can't put that all on one line.  The `IF` needs to be on its own line.

Comment: If you are running within a `BASH` shell then you need to use the proper syntax for that shell.  `IF` is an internal shell command for `BASH` and `CMD.EXE`.  You have to use the proper syntax for the shell you are using.

Comment: Please checkout [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/157787)

Comment: You say bash but the syntax and commands in your above line is batch. Please decide and remove the irrelevant tag. (or specify bash on WSL or whatsoever)

Answer (score 0):

If this is *batch* (as the attempt from the question indicates), according to [[MS.Docs]: Using multiple commands and conditional processing symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490954(v=technet.10)#using-multiple-commands-and-conditional-processing-symbols):

> - **&&** [...]
>
>   command1 **&&** command2
>
>   Use to run the command following **&&** only if the command preceding the symbol is successful. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then runs the second command only if the first command completed successfully.

**Example**:

> ```
> C:\>(tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq svchost.exe" 2>NUL | findstr /I /N "svchost.exe" >NUL) && (echo Program running)
> Program running
>
> C:\>(tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq svchost1.exe" 2>NUL | findstr /I /N "svchost1.exe" >NUL) && (echo Program running)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to over complicate it. Copy the below into a batch file. Also use findstr instead.

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq example.exe" | findstr /i "example.exe" >nul
If %errorlevel%==0 echo example.exe running.
If %errorlevel%==1 echo example.exe Not running.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is even less complicated, *there's no need to filter by `ImageName` when you're using `Find` to filter too*:

```bat
TaskList|Find /I "example.exe">Nul&&(Echo Running)||Echo Not running
```